# Can’t find handles to replace for Square stem

Tags: plumbing

cannot find brand on knobs (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD6xM.jpg)[image][image]

Comment: Try the family owned  hardware store that's been around for 100 years, has weird homebrew mezzanines and generally looks like it belongs on Diagon Alley.

Comment: Thank you! Plumber says they’re going to have to remove all 3 stems and replace, but I hadn’t thought of your suggestion, will give it a shot! Ty again